# Names/list of prominent or well known bhakts of Devi in India

Tags: devi, durga, shakti, shaktism, kali

I’ve been a Hindu-mytho addict for many years now so listened to and watched/read many stories from Hinduism with notable and respected Shiv-bhakts and Vishnu-bhakts.

So, lots of info re bhakts of MahaDev/Narayan, but not as common to find stories of bhakts of Devi.

So far I know of RamaKrishna (Kali) BhamaKepa (Tara) and a few others.

Then like mainstream stories of Maa Bhavani and Shivaji, and things like Ram being ready to cut out his eye in Shakti puja because last lotus was gone in Ramayan, as well as Krishn instructing Pandavs to pray to Durga before war in Mahabharath.

But not so much outside of those.

Who would you guys say are the well-known bhakts of Devi in Indian history ? Or what are other stories of Devi bhakti that are widely known ?

I’d like to learn more regarding this due to my personal faith.

Comment: the samadhi of durgasaptshati and the king with him

Comment: @YOuwillnotknow Thx ! Surath & Samadhi at Medha Rishi ashram. I add to my list :D